# How to update a dictionary with nested list using a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I got the following dictionary, `network_values`

```
network_values = {
    0: "CGR cinémas",
    1: "Ville de Choisy-le-Roi",
    2: "Pathé Gaumont",
    3: "UGC",
    4: "Cinéode",
    5: "Magestic",
    6: "Cinéville",
    7: "cinebus",
    8: "CGR",
    9: "Utopia",
    10: "Écran mobile 74"
}
```

I've another dictionary, `theater_values`, with nested lists

```
theater_values = {
   "0":[
      "node/4522090127",
      1.0,
      300.0,
      "Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port",
      "nan"
   ],
   "1":[
      "node/563839797",
      2.0,
      239.0,
      "Barbezieux-Saint-Hilaire",
      "nan"
   ],
   "2":[
      "node/5472582580",
      "nan",
      "nan",
      "Lezay",
      "nan"
   ],
   "3":[
      "node/7623662713",
      2.0,
      280.0,
      "Montaigu-Vendée",
      "nan"
   ],
   "4":[
      "node/4115072853",
      1.0,
      274.0,
      "Chalonnes-sur-Loire",
      "nan"
   ],
   "5":[
      "node/5250851417",
      3.0,
      341.0,
      "Thiers",
      "nan"
   ],
   "6":[
      "way/83676895",
      3.0,
      534.0,
      "Argentan",
      "nan"
   ],
   "7":[
      "node/502262289",
      8.0,
      1898.0,
      "Tours",
      "CGR cinémas"
   ],
   "8":[
      "node/3475038904",
      "nan",
      "nan",
      "Saint-Étienne",
      "nan"
   ],
   "9":[
      "way/146090090",
      "nan",
      "nan",
      "Marcoussis",
      "nan"
   ],
   "10":[
      "way/66143799",
      "nan",
      "nan",
      "Choisy-le-Roi",
      "Ville de Choisy-le-Roi"
   ],
   "11":[
      "node/7768900435",
      12.0,
      2139.0,
      "Paris",
      "Pathé Gaumont"
   ]
}
```

The aim is when the value like `CGR cinémas` exist in the nested list of `theater_values` and also `network_values`, I update `theater_values` with the keys of `network_values`.

If `CGR cinémas` exist in `network_values` and `theater_values`, I will update the `theater_values` to `0` (integer or character possible).

This is what I've done but it is not doing what it should

```
def proto_csv(theater_values):
    network_values = {0: 'CGR cinémas', 1: 'Ville de Choisy-le-Roi', 2: 'Pathé Gaumont', 3: 'UGC', 4: 'Cinéode', 5: 'Magestic', 6: 'Cinéville', 7: 'cinebus', 8: 'CGR', 9: 'Utopia', 10: 'Écran mobile 74}
    for keys_theaters,vals_theaters in theater_values.items():
        for keys_networks,vals_networks in network_values.items():
            if vals_theaters == vals_networks:
                theater_values[keys_theaters] = str(keys_networks)
    return theater_values
```

I'm a bit confused on how to do it as my code is not giving me the desired results or any results actually...

The updated result would be like that

```
theater_values = {
       "0":[
          "node/4522090127",
          1.0,
          300.0,
          "Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port",
          "nan"
       ],
       "1":[
          "node/563839797",
          2.0,
          239.0,
          "Barbezieux-Saint-Hilaire",
          "nan"
       ],
       "2":[
          "node/5472582580",
          "nan",
          "nan",
          "Lezay",
          "nan"
       ],
       "3":[
          "node/7623662713",
          2.0,
          280.0,
          "Montaigu-Vendée",
          "nan"
       ],
       "4":[
          "node/4115072853",
          1.0,
          274.0,
          "Chalonnes-sur-Loire",
          "nan"
       ],
       "5":[
          "node/5250851417",
          3.0,
          341.0,
          "Thiers",
          "nan"
       ],
       "6":[
          "way/83676895",
          3.0,
          534.0,
          "Argentan",
          "nan"
       ],
       "7":[
          "node/502262289",
          8.0,
          1898.0,
          "Tours",
          "O" #here
       ],
       "8":[
          "node/3475038904",
          "nan",
          "nan",
          "Saint-Étienne",
          "nan"
       ],
       "9":[
          "way/146090090",
          "nan",
          "nan",
          "Marcoussis",
          "nan"
       ],
       "10":[
          "way/66143799",
          "nan",
          "nan",
          "Choisy-le-Roi",
          "Ville de Choisy-le-Roi"
       ],
       "11":[
          "node/7768900435",
          12.0,
          2139.0,
          "Paris",
          "1" #here
       ]
    }
```

Comment: Can yuo give an example of what the updated `network_values` should look like?

Comment: @match sure. Let me update the question. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is to close the quotation marks for `'Écran mobile 74` in your dictionary as the code you pasted returns `SyntaxError`.

Then, in the `if` statement you are currently comparing dictionaries with strings, so the expression is never true. You want to see if the string is in the dictionary values and update that element of the dictionary if so:

```
if vals_networks in vals_theaters:
    theater_values[keys_theaters][vals_theaters.index(vals_networks)] = str(keys_networks)
```

This gives the output:

```
{
    '0': ['node/4522090127', 1.0, 300.0, 'Saint-Jean-Pied-de-Port', 'nan'],
    '1': ['node/563839797', 2.0, 239.0, 'Barbezieux-Saint-Hilaire', 'nan'],
    '2': ['node/5472582580', 'nan', 'nan', 'Lezay', 'nan'],
    '3': ['node/7623662713', 2.0, 280.0, 'Montaigu-Vendée', 'nan'],
    '4': ['node/4115072853', 1.0, 274.0, 'Chalonnes-sur-Loire', 'nan'],
    '5': ['node/5250851417', 3.0, 341.0, 'Thiers', 'nan'],
    '6': ['way/83676895', 3.0, 534.0, 'Argentan', 'nan'],
    '7': ['node/502262289', 8.0, 1898.0, 'Tours', '0'],
    '8': ['node/3475038904', 'nan', 'nan', 'Saint-Étienne', 'nan'],
    '9': ['way/146090090', 'nan', 'nan', 'Marcoussis', 'nan'],
    '10': ['way/66143799', 'nan', 'nan', 'Choisy-le-Roi', '1'],
    '11': ['node/7768900435', 12.0, 2139.0, 'Paris', '2']
}
```